# Fast API error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" , even after converting the 'key' to a tuple

Tags: python, list, dataframe, fastapi

I have a function that fills missing values of a dataframe column with a chosen string or value.

**Code**

## Fill missing values of a column with 'desired values'

```
def fill_num_random_fun(df, col_inputs):
   
   col_name=col_inputs[0]
   col_value=col_inputs[1]
 
   df[col_name]=df[col_name].fillna(value=col_value, inplace=True)
  
   result_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
   for record in result_dict:
        for key, value in record.items():
            if isinstance(value, float):
                record[key] = str(value)
   return result_dict
```

**Main Function**

```
def cleaning_and_analysis(csv_filepath, operation=None, raw_data=None):
     csv_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_filepath) 
     result={}
     if raw_data is not None and isinstance(raw_data, list):
        
        if operation == 'fillWithDesiredValue':
               fill_with_desired_input = raw_data
               result10=fill_num_random_fun(csv_dataframe, fill_with_desired_input)
               if not result:
                  result[tuple(operation)] = [{tuple(raw_data):result10}]
               else:
                  result[tuple(operation)].append({tuple(raw_data):result10})
```

**API**

```
@app.post("/replacement_route")
async def data_cleaning(item: Item):
    # print(item)
    filepath = item.filepath
    operation_name = item.operation
    operands = item.operand
    # print(filepath)
    # print(operation_name)
    # print(operands)
   
    
    cleaned_data = {} # initialize cleaned_data to an empty dictionary
    if len(operands) >=1:
       
        for operand in operands:
            for operation_name,operand_values in operand.items():
                    print(operation_name)
                    print(operand_values)
                    #for i in operand_values:
                        #print("this is ****************",i)
                    cleaned_data.update(cleaning_and_analysis(filepath, operation=operation_name, raw_data=operand_values))
    return cleaned_data
```

**Postman Payload**

```
{
    "filepath": "C:/kidney_disease.csv",
    "operand": [{"fillWithDesiredValue": ["sod",999]}]    
        
}
```

**error at "main" function:**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  at:


 result[tuple(operation)] = [{tuple(raw_data):result10}]

 result[tuple(operation)].append({tuple(raw_data):result10})
```

I used 'tuple' to fix the unhashable list error, but the error still continues.

The postman says: 'Internal Server Error'

I did some debugging. The *filepath, operands, & operation_name* are being extracted properly. The code is failing at 'main function'. How should the error be fixed?

Comment: Most probably `raw_data` is not a list of hashable values but has a list somewhere inside of it.

Comment: Example of what 'raw_data' contains --> ["sod",999] or ["rbc", "great"]. The values in these columns are either integers, floats, or strings.

Comment: What about `operation`?

Comment: 'operation' is "fillWithDesiredValue" & it is present within "operand".  Like this ->     "operand": [{"fillWithDesiredValue": ["sod",999]}]

Comment: Which line is actually triggering the error?

Comment: I specified the lines with the error where I mentioned the error. Here it is ---> error at "main" function:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  at:


 result[tuple(operation)] = [{tuple(raw_data):result10}],

 result[tuple(operation)].append({tuple(raw_data):result10})